# $\mbox{Cap}_p$-measurability

Tags: measure-theory, sobolev-spaces

I found this statement about p-capacity used for the study of Sobolev functions:
"$\mbox{Cap}_p$ is not a Borel measure. In fact, if $0< \mbox{Cap}_p(A) < \infty$, then $A$ is not $\mbox{Cap}_p$-measurable."
I agree with the claim that $\mbox{Cap}_p$ is not a Borel (outer) measure, because balls are not $\mbox{Cap}_p$-measurable, but anyone know a proof of the second part?
When I say "measure", i mean "outer measure".

Comment: Why is $\mbox{Cap}_p$ not an outer measure? When you say _measurability_, do you mean the Caratheodory criterion?

Comment: If $\mu$ is an outer measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$, $A$ is $\mu$-measurable if for every $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, $\mu(B) = \mu(B \cap A) + \mu(B- A)$. An outer measure is said to be a Borel measure if every Borel set is $\mu$-measurable.